# how remove space between two div in different columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one row and two cols which I used in my project and I provided screenshot of the problem I want to remove space between two div in columns please help me
here is my code and I give different color to the columns which I used and inside col I used well now i want to join these two well and remove any padding or margin or space between them how I achieve this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green;">
          <div class="well well-lg" style="margin-top:10px;">
   <img src="admin.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="70" 
            height="50"> <span style="font-size: 20px;"> Admin Name</span>
    </div>
 
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:red;">
   <div class="well well-lg" style="margin-top:10px;">
     <h2 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to Admin Panle</h2>
     
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
       </div>
```

[this is screen shot of mu project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZr6y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new class to your `div` elements and remove `padding/margin` with css. To make it more clear, bootstrap assigns `margin-left: -15px` and `margin-right: -15px` for `.row` selector and `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px` on all `.col-*` selectors to get 30px space between all the cols. To remove this space, you have to set those values for margins and paddings to zero. Here is how you can do it.

Try this code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green;">
            <div class="well well-lg" style="margin-top:10px;"> <img src="admin.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="70" 
        height="50"> <span style="font-size: 20px;"> Admin Name</span> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:red;">
            <div class="well well-lg" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to Admin Panle</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.row.no-gutter {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter > div[class*="col-"] {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Aryan Twanju thanks it works can you explain it in more detail please

Comment: I have added full detail in my answer. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to remove padding on the columns would be to add a .no-pad class to your .row:

```
 <div class="row no-pad">
...and then add this CSS.

.row.no-pad {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

> I suggest you to use Bootstrap 4, because Bootstrap 4 now includes a
>   .no-gutters class that you can just add to the .row.

```
  <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
```

Bootstrap 4: http://www.codeply.com/go/OBW3RK1ErD